# ColdFusion's EntityLoad missing last record

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion

EntityLoad with 1 argument is supposed to return all records in a table.

However, if I call it immediately after an EntityNew and EntitySave (which inserts a new record) that last record appears to be missing from the results.

I get the record back fine if I instead pass in a filter or if I call EntityLoadByPk. I realize one would probably not want to get a record just inserted within the same request, but I would still like to know what is going on here.

```
local.e = EntityNew("e");
local.e.setDescription("lorem ipsum");
EntitySave(local.e);
local.id = local.e.getId();

//fails to get record inserted above
dump(EntityLoad("e"));

//gets record inserted above successfully
dump(EntityLoadByPk("e", local.id));
```

Comment: I highly recommend reviewing these blog posts from Brian Kotek - http://www.briankotek.com/blog/index.cfm/ObjectRelational-Mapping - regarding ORM Sessions. Mark Mandel also has some good posts on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with Hibernate sessions and when the SQL to save an entity actually gets run. I am not an expert so its difficult to explain the 'workflow'.

One way I use to get around this issue is to wrap the entitySave() in a transaction.

```
transaction{
    EntitySave(local.e);
}
```

Comment: Ah, that worked. From reading a little bit further the default behavior is to do an ORMFlush() at the end of each request. The part I still don't understand though is why the other calls were able to pick up the new record in the same request.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate doesn't persist any datauntil the request ends, so you can't retrieve a record that has been EntitySave()d in the same request.

You can run ORMFlush() after your entitySave() and before your entityLoad().

```
local.e = EntityNew("e");
local.e.setDescription("lorem ipsum");
EntitySave(local.e);
local.id = local.e.getId();

//persist any dirty records so they are loaded in the next EntityLoad()
ORMFlush();

//fails to get record inserted above
dump(EntityLoad("e"));
```